# Select 2 or more values in the IF statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to implement following logic in my SQL query:
If some date is not set or it's year is 1970 then select `real_date` flag to null AND change date to current data, else - `real_date` is `true` and no need to change date.
`real_date` is not an actual field in the table but a flag I need to set up.

I can easily do this using 2 lines in my `SELECT` section:

```
, IF (actualDate is NULL OR YEAR(actualDate) = 1970, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), actualDate) as actual_date
, IF (actualDate is NULL OR YEAR(actualDate) = 1970, null, true) as real_date
```

And the question - is it the only way to do it? Don't really like the fact that I had to copy condition again. Can somehow the second select be moved to the first one?

**Update:** I need to select both `actualDate` (it will be either fixed to current time version or the actual stored value) and `real_date` (which will be true or false/null). Maybe I am missing something, but how could COALESCE function help here?

**Update 2:** Thanks again everyone. Learnt other ways to write it but all of them have check in 2 places. My idea was to have logical condition in only one place but doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: *‘If some date is not set or it's year is 1970 then select `real_date` flag to null’* – but your example does the opposite: `IF (YEAR(actualDate) = 1970 OR actualDate is NULL, true, null)` will yield `null` if `actualDate` contains a non-NULL date set outside the year 1970.

Comment: your way looks fine (mostly).  However, test for NULL FIRST, then the year of actual...  For the flag of real_date, I would explicitly return  ..., true, false ) as real_date

Comment: Thanks, Andriy. Edited code (that was typo). DRapp, ok, but why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variant is pretty and comfortable for supporting code in future, do not change anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function.

> Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `CASE WHEN ... THEN ... END` (with multiple WHEN) instead of the two `IF`

`
Check this here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

But the COALESCE function can do the job for this case.

Answer (score 1):

I might try something like this instead:

```
…
, COALESCE(NULLIF(actualDate, '1970-01-01'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) AS actual_date
, NULLIF(actualDate <> '1970-01-01', false) AS is_real_date
…
```

Or maybe the second `NULLIF()` is not really necessary? Consider this:

```
…
, COALESCE(NULLIF(actualDate, '1970-01-01'), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) AS actual_date
, (actualDate <> '1970-01-01') AS is_real_date
…
```

The second column could then be `true`, `false` or `NULL`, and you could treat `NULL` same as `false`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most compact form I can think of using `COALESCE` and without repeating any comparison:

```
select id, type, real_date, if(real_date, actual_date, now()) as actual_date
from (
  select *, coalesce(year(actual_date), 1970) != 1970 as real_date from table1
) as subResult
```

Working [example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a0c7/11)